# Change URL in Nginx Config

Tags: nginx, configuration, wordpress

How can I change url to go to only one location rather than request coming from.

URL :

- www.example.com/blog is going to /var/www/blog (which is correct)
- www.example.com/blog/abc should go to /var/www/blog instead of /var/www/blog/abc

  ```
  location /blog {
    alias /var/www/blog;
    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SO 30 characters minimum rule is ridiculous.

`rewrite ^/blog/abc$ /blog;`

Comment: How about this - rewrite ^/blog/*$ /blog; Will this work?

Comment: It will rewrite everything after `blog`, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: I want all requests with /blog(/blog or /blog/abc or /blog/page/2)  to point to /blog folder. And it shouldn't redirect to /blog. It should process in /blog.

Comment: @Chopra No, you do not want to do that. If you were somehow able to configure it, you would then get a 404 on every static file!

Comment: Any way to use if else statements here. I want to use ^/blog/ but not ^/blog/ wp-content or wp-includes.